# Sequelize include model from different database schema

Tags: sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js, backend

I have 2 models:

1. Product
2. Brand

They are in different databases.
I need to parse Brands by `value` from Product.

As I understand - I need to use `include`, but I can't do it because sequelizer is trying to get the Product model from the Brand database.

How to include a table from another database in the query?

Comment: I assume you are using php here to communicate with your database?

Comment: Please state what Databases you are using. MySql?

Comment: Surely you only want two tables not databases?

Comment: You can easily do it at the time of creating Sequelize database connection object. You have to add one more line. For example.

const ProductsDb = new Sequelize(config.productsDatabaseName, config.username, config.password, config.options);
ProductsDb.dialect.supports.schemas = true;

Then at the time of creating models add like this

{
      tableName: "product",
      timestamps: false,
      schema: "products" // add this line
    }

Now you can create multiple complex queries using tables from different databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequelize sets its database on initialisation and only supports a single one. You could initialise two sequelize objects, each with a different database. However you are not going to be able to use both in a single query